# Actionscript Mouse event problem

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i am trying to implement the following control on a movieclip object. When the mouse pointer is over the object and if the left mouse button is clicked and stays clicked then a mask that overlaps the movieclip object is starting to disappear. I tried the MouseEvent.DOWN, etc but i did not succeed to implement this functionality. Probably i miss something. Can i achieve this through standard mouse events types or do i have to implement it another way?
 Also is it possible instead to fade out the mask by reducing the alpha attribute, to actually make dissappear the pixel(s) that under the mouse pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

`MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`/`Mouse.MOUSE_UP` are indeed the events to use so there most be a problem in your code.

It often happens this event doesn't get triggered because of objects overlapping and I suspect in this case it might be the mask. If this is the case you can simply disabling mouseEvents on the obstructive displayObjects with `mouseEnabled = false`.

**Example :**

```
var background:Sprite,
    foreground:Sprite; // Note: could be MovieClips of course !

// adds a sprite with a pink circle
addChild(background = new Sprite());
background.graphics.beginFill(0xff0099);
background.graphics.drawEllipse(0,0,100,100);

// adds a sprite containing a black box and adds it on top of the circle
addChild(foreground = new Sprite());
foreground.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
foreground.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);

background.buttonMode = true; // not necessary, just adds the handcursor on rollover to let you debug easier.
foreground.mouseEnabled = false; // the foreground is not clickable anymore, which makes the background clickable


background.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

function onMouseUp(e:Event):void
{
    foreground.visible = 0; // I let you do the animation here ; )
}
```

**A few quick hints regarding the pixel under the cursor :**

You can do it with a [Bitmap](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) object.
The pixel coordinates can be retrieved with mouseX, mouseY (note that bitmap objects don't dispatch mouse events so you need to add it to a sprite to use as a wrapper).
You can retrieve the pixels actual color/alpha by [getPixel32](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel32()) and modify it by [setPixel32](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixel32()).

If you are having troubles I suggest you open a separate question for that.

Hope it helps,
T.

Comment: thanks Theo actually i achieve the effect i wanted by using correctly the MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_UP, AND MOUSE_MOVE events. Actually i registered two separate events for each MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_UP. In MOUSE_UP i include a object.removeEventListener(MOUSE_MOVE, mousedown)   and in MOUSE_DOWN i include a object.addEventListener(MOUSE_MOVE, mousedown)  plus the actions i want to  triger.